# Compile coq without the standard library

Tags: compilation, coq

I am compiling Coq often to test some changes, but this process is really slow because the standard library in `theories/` takes time to compile.

Is it possible to generate a "lightweight" version of Coq for experiments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do to avoid this is that I `make bin/coqtop` (or any flavor of the binary you use) instead of plain `make`. It only recompile the binary. Be careful that some commands rely on the std (mostly on the prelude, with the definition of basic types) so you might have to recompile everything from time to time if you modify the theories.

Hope it helps,

V.

(Just in case it changes anything, I always give the `-local`  flag to configure).

Comment: Thanks! I also just heard about the `make states` command to build a minimalistic Coq.

Comment: @Clarus You comment deserves to be an answer, if you expand a bit on it.